# A problem with Order-Dense set Definition

Tags: elementary-set-theory, order-theory

I have a problem with the following definition of a order-dense set.

**Definition:**
Suppose $\succ$ is a binary relation on an uncountable set $X$. A subset $Z$ of $X$ is called $\succ$-*order dense* if for all $x,y \in X$ such that $x \succ y$ exists some $z \in Z$ with $x\succsim z \succsim y$.

So here there is my problem: how do we move from $\succ$ to $\succsim$? Indeed, if $x\succsim z \succsim y$, there is the possibility in the end that $x\succsim y$, which is not really what we started from. Indeed, somewhere else I found a definition that starts from $\succ$ and ends with $\succ$ preserving the strict order.

Thanks in advance for any feedback.

Comment: Where did you find this definition? There is a standard definition of *dense order* and it involves only $<$, not $\leq$.

Comment: It is quite standard in the theory of choice. Maybe I should add that $X$ has to be uncountable.

Comment: I made an edit. Btw, what I do lack is the intuition, if it is possible to build it on this point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $x\in Z$, you can just choose $z= x$. Similarly, if $y \in Z$, just take $z = y$. Thus your definition can be rephrased as follows: for all $x,y \in X \setminus Z$ such that $x > y$, there exists some $z \in Z$ with $x \geq z \geq y$, ... or $x > z > y$ since now the two conditions are equivalent.

Comment: Take $Z=\Bbb Z$ the integers. Then $\Bbb Z$ is not order-dense if we require $x>z>y$, but it "becomes" order-dense is we allow $x\ge z\ge y$.